# How to get the first image and display it ? firebase flutter

Tags: flutter

[firestore database with the collections and fields, want to retrieve out the first image from the array in the collection and display it using flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KnCq.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Image.network(imagesUrl.first),
```

Or:

```
Image.network(
  imagesUrl[0],
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
```